# Git stuck at deltafying objects

Tags: git, visual-studio, push, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

My source code ( with pictures ) size is ~500MB.
**But I can't push it to any git repository**: My git push attempt is stucked at "deltafying objects" in VS.
I watched my network in: ~3kb/s. out: 100kb/s. But still not pushing.

Here is a screenshot from visual studio:

[image]

I tried in visual studio, to push it Visual Studio Team Services (with git) didn't work. I tried sourcetree(v1.9.6.1) for checking it to bitbucket. Didn't work. I tried git console, didn't work.

My Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 has "Git-2.9.3.2-64bit" also this git version installed on my machine.

**Update:** More information: I tried on source-tree again, here is console output;

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream LeanStartup master:master  
POST git-receive-pack (163209032 bytes)  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054  
Pushing to https://*****@bitbucket.org/*****/leanstartup.git  
Everything up-to-date  
Completed with errors, see above.
```

**Update 2**: I tried on another solution ( just changed 1-2 things to commit and push). My git in Visual Studio & Source Tree is working well.
So maybe I need to suspect for one solution "leanstartup"?.
I tried to delete files: "`.gitattributes`" "`.gitignore`" and folder: "`.git`" on solution folder to re-assign the git source control.
But again, It hangs on "deltafying objects".
Do you I need to delete more git data from somewhere else to clear all git-assigment on this project?

What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: How long is it stuck? Do you eventually cancel, or does it halt in some other way (such as with an error message)? Is the CPU busy while this is happening?

Comment: Note that "didn't work" is not a good description. Did SourceTree and git console get stuck with the same message? Did they say anything other than that?

Comment: It pushes for a long, long time. I didn't hit the cancel button on my first and second attempt. Cpu is working at %1 - %2 for this process SourceTree. ( Intel i7 desktop pc. )

Comment: Sorry, visual studio and source tree gives error message something like this "remote server closed the connection". I will get the message again to post here...

Comment: I updated my question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I solved my question. I think I'm getting timeout when git says "deltafying objects". Because my upload speed is very low thanks to TTNET ( internet provider in Turkey, which sucks )

So, I tried to do this with my company internet; It's uploaded in 1 minutes.
Thanks for help though...

Comment: If Deltafying on Visual Studio is taking too much time, you can also try at the command line on the git project directory:  git push -u origin --all

Comment: Or you can use Super Online :)