# Visual Studio GitHub stuck at Deltafying Objects

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio and its integrated GitHub feature. Now when committing and  subsequently syncing the changes to the GitHub server, the progress is stuck at "Deltafying objects". After some time, it throws an error. Something like, 'Error syncing changes with the server'.

[image]

What I did - Tried google. The only result concerning this problem is the following: [Git stuck at deltafying objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199201/git-stuck-at-deltafying-objects), which however doesn't much help as the problem for them was solved by changing the Internet connection from a very slow type to somewhat faster. This doesn't much apply to these circumstances, as I'm running a 100K VDSL connection and it had worked ever since!

I'm pretty much left for dead without syncing to GitHub. Any ideas?